# Python matching dashes using Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex

I am currently new to Regular Expressions and would appreciate if someone can guide me through this.

```
import re
some = "I cannot take this B01234-56-K-9870 to the house of cards"
```

I have the above string and trying to extract the string with dashes (B01234-56-K-9870) using python regular expression. I have following code so far:

```
regex = r'\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+'
match = re.search(regex, some)
print(match.group()) #returns B01234-56-K-9870
```

Is there any simpler way to extract the dash pattern using regular expression? For now,  I do not care about the order or anything. I just wanted it to extract string with dashes.

Comment: `\w+(?:-\w+)+` would do it. If you expect exactly 3 dashes then `\w+(?:-\w+){3}`

Comment: It looks like your data is in a specific format. It is okay to express that properly in the regex.

Comment: There is nothing particularly *wrong* with your regex. Just know that `\w` matches the `_` as well. Personally, I would find out if there is a more identifiable pattern and use that, such as `(?:[A-Z\d]+-){3}\d+` if the final group is always digits and the first three groups are all caps and digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex (as shortened by [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird)),

```
\w+-\S+
```

Original regex: `(?=\w+-)\S+`

---

### Explanation:

- `\w+-` matches 1 or more words followed by a `-`
- `\S+` matches non-space characters

[Regex demo!](https://regex101.com/r/p7ex6n/4)

Comment: Thank you for explanation. If I wanted to to capture only 3 dashes, how would I achieve that?

Comment: Then, use `\w+(?:-\w+){3}` as said by [MonkeyZeus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219143/python-matching-dashes-using-regular-expressions/65219192?noredirect=1#comment115300425_65219143)

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo for pointing that out ;-)

Comment: You don't need the lookahead, you can just match it.